# Saving JSON property values to Model

Tags: .net, json

I would like to iterate over my JSON data which I am returning and looks like this for example:

```
"id": 9493731,
"due_at": null,
"unlock_at": null,
"lock_at": null,
"points_possible": 1,
"grading_type": "pass_fail",
"assignment_group_id": 2645710,
"grading_standard_id": null,
"created_at": "2016-04-13T18:30:41Z",
"updated_at": "2016-08-04T05:30:03Z",
"peer_reviews": false,
"automatic_peer_reviews": false,
"position": 6,
"grade_group_students_individually": null,
"anonymous_peer_reviews": null,
"group_category_id": null
```

I would like to retrieve the property names and save them to my model which looks like this:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CanvasAPI.Model
{
    public class Assignment
    {
        [Key]
        public int? AssignmentID { get; set; }
        public int? id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string created_at { get; set; }
        public string updated_at { get; set; }
        public string due_at { get; set; }
        public string lock_at { get; set; }
        public string unlock_at { get; set; }
        public bool has_overrides { get; set; }
        //public All_Dates[] all_dates { get; set; }
        public int? course_id { get; set; }
        public string html_url { get; set; }
        public string submissions_download_url { get; set; }
        public int? assignment_group_id { get; set; }
        public string[] allowed_extensions { get; set; }
        public bool turnitin_enabled { get; set; }
        //public Turnitin_Settings turnitin_settings { get; set; }
        public string originality_report_visibility { get; set; }
        public bool s_paper_check { get; set; }
        public bool internet_check { get; set; }
        public bool journal_check { get; set; }
        public bool exclude_biblio { get; set; }
        public bool exclude_quoted { get; set; }
        public string exclude_small_matches_type { get; set; }
        public int? exclude_small_matches_value { get; set; }
        public bool grade_group_students_individually { get; set; }
        //public External_Tool_Tag_Attributes external_tool_tag_attributes { get; set; }
        public bool peer_reviews { get; set; }
        public bool automatic_peer_reviews { get; set; }
        public int? peer_review_count { get; set; }
        public string peer_reviews_assign_at { get; set; }
        public bool anonymous_peer_reviews { get; set; }
        public bool moderated_grading { get; set; }
        public int? group_category_id { get; set; }
        public int? needs_grading_count { get; set; }
        //public Needs_Grading_Count_By_Section[] needs_grading_count_by_section { get; set; }
        public int? position { get; set; }
        public bool post_to_sis { get; set; }
        public string integration_id { get; set; }
        public string integration_data { get; set; }
        public bool muted { get; set; }
        public bool has_submitted_submissions { get; set; }
        public float? points_possible { get; set; }
        public string submission_types { get; set; }
        public string grading_type { get; set; }
        public int? grading_standard_id { get; set; }
        public bool published { get; set; }
        public bool unpublishable { get; set; }
        public bool only_visible_to_overrides { get; set; }
        public bool locked_for_user { get; set; }
        //public Lock_Info lock_info { get; set; }
        public string lock_explanation { get; set; }
        public int? quiz_id { get; set; }
        public bool anonymous_submissions { get; set; }
        public string discussion_topic { get; set; }
        public bool freeze_on_copy { get; set; }
        public bool frozen { get; set; }
        public string[] frozen_attributes { get; set; }
        public string submission { get; set; }
        public bool use_rubric_for_grading { get; set; }
        public string rubric_settings { get; set; }
        //public Rubric[] rubric { get; set; }
        public int?[] assignment_visibility { get; set; }
        //public Override[] overrides { get; set; }

 }
```

I am able to iterate through the JSON data and retrieve the values but I am having trouble trying to save the data to the model.

Here is what I have so far:

```
                            Assignment assignment = new Assignment();

                            foreach (string myVal in name_list)
                            {
                                if (item[myVal].ToString() != string.Empty)
                                {
                                var a = "assignment" + "." + myVal;
             **problem here -->**   a = item[myVal].ToString();
                                }
                            }

                            db.Assignments.Add(assignment);db.SaveChanges();`
```

How can I assign the property names and values dynamically to my model so that I can save the changes?

Comment: Don't do that - use newtonsoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use newtonsoft.json to achieve this.
Heres a link to an example:
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm

Your code should look like this:

```
Assignment assignment = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Assignment>(jsonString);
```

The json is desearized into the object, mapping the properties by name.

Hope it helps

Comment: Ok. I'm getting further on this but now I am getting an error    `Error Reading String. Unexpected token` and it points to this section of  my JSON data which looks like: `"integration_data": {}` As you can see there is no data in that property. What is the best way to handle this within the deserialize method?

Comment: It turns out that integration_data was actually an object. I just created another class in my model and have gotten past this issue.